# How to scroll the Browser using watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

When I use Watir-webdriver, I couldn't find any function to scroll the window, while I was using watir-classic, I was using this 'b.label(:text,'some').document.scrollintoview', but I don't find any statement while I am using watir-webdriver, Can you anyone tell me what's the corresponding function watir-webdriver?

Comment: Justin Ko, I searched it and I haven't found any link,So that I posted it here, and your answer perfectly answers my question and I knew of this scroll function but I forgotten that separate gem needs to be installed. And If you want, I would delete this question. Thank you very much.

Comment: There's a gem called `watir-scroll` that may assist you here

Comment: yes , I found in the original like which Justin Ko has pointed out, thanks anyway.